# Parsing a String in Ruby (Regexp?)

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a string

```
Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024
```

Can anyone help me with parsing this? I tried using StringScanner but I'm sort of unfamiliar with regular expressions (not very much practice).

If I could separate it into

```
myarray[0] = {type => "Purchases", id="10384839"}
myarray[1] = {type => "Purchases", id="10293900"}
myarray[2] = {type => "Purchases", id="20101024"}
```

That'd be awesome!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string = "Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024"
string.scan(/(\w+)\s+(\d+)/).collect { |type, id| { :type => type, :id => id }}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Rutger's solution, but this feels a little more Ruby-ish to me. +1

Comment: This answer has saved me <3

Answer (score 11):

You could do it with a regexp, or just do it in Ruby:

```
myarray = str.split(",").map { |el| 
    type, id = el.split(" ")
    {:type => type, :id => id } 
}
```

Now you can address it like 'myarray[0][:type]'.

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression wouldn't be necessary, and probably wouldn't be the clearest way to do it. The method you need in this case is `split`. Something like this would work

```
raw_string = "Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024"
myarray = raw_string.split(',').collect do |item|
  type, id = item.split(' ', 2)
  { :type => type, :id => id }
end
```

Documentation for the split and collect methods can be found here:

[Enumerable.collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect)
[String.split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an irb session:

```
dru$ irb
irb(main):001:0> x = "Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024"
=> "Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024"
irb(main):002:0> items = x.split ','
=> ["Purchases 10384839", "Purchases 10293900", "Purchases 20101024"]
irb(main):006:0> items.map { |item| parts = item.split ' '; { :type => parts[0], :id => parts[1] } }
=> [{:type=>"Purchases", :id=>"10384839"}, {:type=>"Purchases", :id=>"10293900"}, {:type=>"Purchases", :id=>"20101024"}]
irb(main):007:0>
```

Essentially, I would just split on the ',' first. Then I would split each item by space and create the hash object with the parts. No regex required.

Comment: No regexp required, but maybe regexp recommended? I wonder which one would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
   s = 'Purchases 10384839,Purchases 10293900,Purchases 20101024'
   myarray = s.split(',').map{|item| 
       item = item.split(' ')
       {:type => item[0], :id => item[1]} 
   }
```

Comment: Just a quick question: what's the difference between `map` and `collect`?